# grDevices holding file open

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpy2

I'm working on a proof of concept using rpy2 to tie an existing R package to a web service. I do have the source to the package, if that is needed to fix this issue. I'm also currently developing on Windows, but if this problem is solved by using Linux instead, that's fine, as that's my planned environment.

For my first point in this POC, I'm trying to capture a chart made by this package, and serve it up to a web request using Flask. The complete code:

```python
from flask import Flask, Response
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from os import path

app = Flask(__name__)

null = ro.r("NULL")
numeric = ro.r("numeric")
grdevices = importr("grDevices")
efm = importr('euroformix')

@app.route('/')
def index():    
    table = efm.tableReader('stain.txt')
    list = efm.sample_tableToList(table)

    with TemporaryDirectory() as dir_name:
        print("Working in {0}".format(dir_name))
        png_path = path.join(dir_name, "epg_mix.png")
        print("png path {0}".format(png_path))
        grdevices.png(file=png_path, width=512, height=512)
        # Do Data Science Stuff Here
        grdevices.dev_off()

        with open(png_path, 'rb') as f:
            png = f.read()
            return Response(png, "image/png")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When hitting the service, I get back `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\matt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpgg65cagq\\epg_mix.png'`

Looking at the call stack, it happens when `TempDirectory()` goes to clean up. Using the Flask debugger, the `png` variable is empty, also.

So, how do I make `grDevices` close the file? Or do I need to go about my POC a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpy2` is not fully supported on Windows and what is working on Linux (or OS X) might not. Since you are developing a PoC with Flask, I'd encourage you to try using Docker (with `docker-machine` on Windows). You could use rpy2's docker image as a base image.

However, here this is just using the R functions `png()` and `dev.off()` so it "should" work.

I have 3 suggestions:

---

1-

Does your "Do Data Science stuff" block make any R plot ? If not this would explain why your Python object `png` is empty.

---

2-

If using R's `grid` system (e.g., through `lattice` or `ggplot2`) and you are evaluating strings as R code it is preferable to explicitly ask R to plot the figure. For example:

```
p <- ggplot(mydata) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
print(p)
```

rather than

```
ggplot(mydata) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
```

---

3-

Try moving `return Response(png, "image/png")` to outside the context manager block for `TemporaryDirectory`

Comment: The whole "Do Data Science Stuff" block calls a function which eventually invokes `plot()`, `text()`, `polygon()` and others. Running on Windows, I do get the graphics windows popping up. I'm working on getting as linux vm set up for this. which is leading to an excursion into Xvfb.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not currently have a Windows version to try this on. Strange that a Windows is popping up. Otherwise, on Linux you should not need X11/xorg to plot R PNG graphics. Hard to be able to help more without a self-contained example to try try replicating the issue.

Comment: I'm now running the app under linux, and it works perfectly. So I guess it's just something with Windows' behavior of sharing files vs posix.